# Run function after jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have this function for inserting more image posts into my web page. After it is inserts the images, the div that is has the image inside of it resizes to be the same width as the image. However the issue I am having is that it is running before the images have loaded so the divs are not being resized.

Any ideas how I can set it to run when all the images are loaded?

```
function load_more(url, page, page_name) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/app/load_more/" + page_name + "/pagename/" + url,
        data: 'id=testdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(".next").remove();
            $("#top").append(data['top']);
            $("#bottom").append(data['bottom']);
            $('.img-wrap').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('img').attr('src') != "") {
                    $(this).animate({
                        width: $(this).find('img').css("width")
                    }, 300);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `load` event on the image to wait for them to load:

```
$('.img-wrap').each(function() { 
  var div = $(this);
  var img = div.find('img');
  if (img.attr('src') != ""){
    img.on('load', function(){
      div.animate({
        width: img.css("width")
      }, 300);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an onload event on img tags that is fired when the image loads. Have you tried this

```
$(document).on('load', 'img', function(){
// resize
});
```

you also need to check the complete attribute and trigger the load event if it is true

```
var $img = $(this).find('img'); 
if ($(this).find('img').attr('src') != "" && $img.get(0).complete){
    $img.trigger('load);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Guffa has mentioned, I might even move the non-data-dependent portion of your code into the .ajax complete callback:

```
 function load_more(url, page, page_name) {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "/app/load_more/" + page_name + "/pagename/" + url,
         data: 'id=testdata',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         success: function (data) {
             $(".next").remove();
             $("#top").append(data['top']);
             $("#bottom").append(data['bottom']);
         },
         complete: function () {
             $('.img-wrap').each(function () {
                 var div = $(this);
                 var img = div.find('img');
                 if (img.attr('src') != "") {
                     img.load(function () {
                         div.animate({
                             width: img.css("width")
                         }, 300);
                     });
                 }
             });
         }
     });
 }
```